# What package should I use for single/double quoted inline text according to babel settings?

Tags: babel, languages, quotation, portability

#### tl;dr

What package and command should I use to write double quoted text or single quoted text depending on whether I set `babel` to English or Italian?

Specifically, I'm not referring to quotes used for direct speach but those used to mark things like *gimme water* in *The sentence "gimme water" means xyz*, which I see it's rendered as `` The sentence `gimme water' means xyz `` in an English book, but which I think I should render as ``` The sentence ``gimme water'' means xyz ``` according to Italian conventions, I believe.

By the way, I'm prefectly open to try out LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

#### Some background

I'm translating a book from English to Italian, and so far I haven't bothered changing `` `quoted text' `` to ``` ``testo virgolettato'' ```, fundamentally because I don't if that's what I'm supposed to do, i.e. I don't know if English uses single quotes where Italian uses double quotes.

Whatever the answer to *that* question is, the point is that so far I have just written a few pages out of a few hundreds, so a search and substitute is managable, but doing it when I'll have finished the translation will be problematic, becasuse whether a `'` is an apostrphe (very frequent in italian) or a closing single quote is context sensitive (e.g. in `` `un testo' un po' strano `` and `` `un po' di testo' strano `` the two `'`s have inverted function, and you can't tell which is which if I cover `testo` and `po` with my fingers).

So at the moment I'd like to change every `` `quoted text' `` to something like `\quoted{quoted text}`, which I'd expect `\usepackage[italian]{babel}` to resolve to whatever I'm supposed to use in Italian. Maybe

Comment: I think the package `csquotes` supports this.

Comment: csquotes and `\enquote`.

Comment: You could use the `semantic-markup` package which provides `\quoted{}`. For non-US quotation conventions, `\usepackage[defaultquotes]{semantic-markup}` and also load `babel` with the chosen language.

Answer (score 1):

I’ll assume `italian` as the main language.

**The approach with shorthands.** Admittedly a bit involved. Here `*italian` and `*english` mean user language-dependent shorthands.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english, italian]{babel}

\useshorthands*{"}

\defineshorthand[*italian]{"`}{``}
\defineshorthand[*italian]{"'}{''}
\defineshorthand[*english]{"`}{`}
\defineshorthand[*english]{"'}{'}

\addto\extrasitalian{\languageshorthands{italian}}
\addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{english}}

\begin{document}

The sentence "`gimme water"' means xyz.

\selectlanguage{english}

The sentence "`gimme water"' means xyz.

\end{document}
```

**The approach with `\quoted`.** Besides `csquotes`, which is the preferred option, with `babel` and its hooking mechanism you can do the following. The first `\AddBabelHook` sets code to be executed always with each language selector; the second one sets code for `english`, which is executed last.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english, italian]{babel}

\newcommand\quoted[1]{``#1''}

\AddBabelHook{quoted}{afterextras}{%
  \renewcommand\quoted[1]{``##1''}}

\AddBabelHook[english]{quoted}{afterextras}{%
  \renewcommand\quoted[1]{`##1'}}

\begin{document}

The sentence \quoted{gimme water} means xyz.

\selectlanguage{english}

The sentence \quoted{gimme water} means xyz.

\end{document}
```

**Approach with luatex and transforms**. This approach is only possible if there are more or less clear rules for transforming the quotes, which is not your case. However, as an illustration, here is a very crude converter, just ignoring `'` can be an apostrophe. Note `’` (the real Unicode character) is not converted, which means this solution might be useful if quotes are left as `` ` `` and `'` (as a sort of markup), and you convert the apostrophes instead.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english, italian]{babel}

\babelprehyphenation{italian}{ ` }{ string = “ }
\babelprehyphenation{italian}{ ' }{ string = ” }

\begin{document}

The sentence `gimme water' means’ xyz.

\selectlanguage{english}

The sentence `gimme water' means’ xyz.

\end{document}
```